# Gradle Sonar call returns error that Node.js 16 is not supported

Tags: node.js, gradle, sonarqube

When calling 'gradlew sonar', I get the message "Node.js version 16 is not supported, you might experience issues. Please use a supported version of Node.js [10, 12, 14, 15]"

Yet, according to Sonar (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/javascript/), Node 16 is supported.

What is correct now?

I use the Gradle Sonarqube Plugin 3.3, Gradle 7.3.3 and Node 16.13.2.

Comment: This depends on the server version. If you scroll back in the documentation versions, you'll find out that this support was introduced in 9.1, while you may be running 8.9 (latest LTS).